Qt 6.8 How to force QML Camera to focus again
I'm porting an Android Qt 5.7 app to Qt 6.8.
The app uses the QML Camera module to take some photos and it also uses an "invisible button" covering almost all viewport to force a re-focus of the camera.
The associated code to achieve this in Qt 5.7 is:
    // Tap-Focus operation
    CameraInvisibleButton {
        id: focusTapArea
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height - 2*captureButton.height
        visible: camera.cameraStatus == Camera.ActiveStatus && camera.focus.isFocusModeSupported(Camera.FocusAuto)
        opacity: 0

        onClicked: {
            console.info("focusTap clicked. Camera lockStatus:", camera.lockStatus)
            if (camera.lockStatus == Camera.Searching)
                return;
            camera.unlock();
            camera.searchAndLock();
        }
    }

The associated functions of the above code snippet (camera.unlock() / lock() / searchAndLock()) are now obsolete. The documentation of Qt-6 mentions:

On hardware that supports it, QCamera lets you adjust the focus and zoom. This also includes ? functionality such as a "Macro" mode for close up work (e.g. reading barcodes, or recognizing letters), or "touch to focus" - indicating an interesting area of the image for the hardware to attempt to focus on.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#focusPoint-prop

...but there is no example of how to achieve the "touch to focus" operation.
Do you have any idea?
PS: I'm not interested to focus on a specific tap point, I just want to force a re-focus of the camera to its default focus point.

In the Qt6 documentation, it gives you the following example on how to configure a custom focus point:
    CaptureSession {
        camera: Camera {
            id: camera
            focusMode: Camera.FocusModeAutoNear
            customFocusPoint: Qt.point(0.2, 0.2) // Focus relative to top-left corner
        }
        videoOutput: videoOutput
    }

So if you were to implement a TapHandler and normalize the input you can set the customFocusPoint. As you're not looking for a customFocusPoint but just the normal auto focus point, your Qt5.15 logic pretty much is a go.
Through trial and error, we discovered the need for a toggleFocus() function. In Qt5.x, we found on some platforms, unlock() triggers a refocus; on others, searchAndLock() does. We train users to perform an action, like tap-and-hold, to call this function and repeat if it fails.
// Qt5.x toggleFocus
function toggleFocus() {
    if (camera.lockStatus !== Camera.Unlocked) {
        camera.unlock();
    else {
        camera.searchAndLock();
    }
}

To port this to Qt6.x, I suppose you could try something like:
function toggleFocus() {
    if (camera.focusMode !== Camera.FocusModeAuto)
        camera.focusMode = Camera.FocusModeAuto;
    else
        camera.focusMode = Camera.FocusModeManual;
}

Additional tips for achieving better focus include further user training, such as holding the camera above the target object and pulling back to a distance of 30–50 cm, which often resets the focus. For scanning small items like barcodes, we typically recommend setting the zoomFactor to around 2, since relying more on hardware zoom or software digital zoom and less on macro focus helps mitigate focus issues. We tried to train the users to use pinch-to-zoom instead of moving their phones closer for better focusing, but it was more difficult for them to adopt.

Unfortunately Camera.customFocusPoint requires Camera.FocusModeManual and both of them are not supported in all devices but thanks for the hint.
I finally decided to use something like this:
if (camera.zoomFactor !== 1)
camera.zoomTo(1, 0)
else
camera.zoomTo(1.01, 0)
